# Top right drop down menu bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image: menu]

This menu on the top right -I suppose- should be a drop down. But sometimes when I click it, they send me to another page. For example when I click review menu button, I go to [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review) page instead of seeing the review drop down, or when I click the most right button, I go to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) instead of seeing the drop down.

I am not even sure if this is a bug. I tried to reproduce it but couldn't, it feels very random. Maybe someone here can reproduce it.

Note: I am on Firefox latest version and Windows 10

**Edit:** I think it might be possible to reproduce it by clicking the menu buttons at the very start of loading the page. I enter the site and instantly click one of the menu buttons, they usually go to the related page instead of drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that icon leads to https://stackexchange.com. If you hover over it, and have the status bar of your browser enabled, you'll see the proof:

[image]

*However*, there is some JavaScript which disables that behaviour, and opens the 'site switcher dialog' instead. But that only works if the JavaScript is loaded; it's a separate (cached) file and if you have a slow internet connection, it might not load before you click that icon.

The behaviour is the way it is because some users have JavaScript disabled, and the site is still functional for them. For more reference, see [Clicking the top bar sometimes loads the SE homepage, sometimes shows the site switcher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231150/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.